# Is it good to define localhost as 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file?

Tags: configuration, ip, localhost, hosts

I just came across a server that does not respond to things like `ping localhost` or `mysql -h localhost` - I believe this is because localhost is not defined in the hosts file.

On just about every machine I've used `localhost` has been an entry in the hosts file. Is there any good reasons not to define it - like possible security concerns? Or is this something that probably should be configured by default and perhaps is just missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's good. As you've already found out, there are certain programs (like mysql) that expect to be able to connect to localhost. Without that entry in your hosts file, programs cannot resolve that name to the proper IP address (in this case, the loopback address of 127.0.0.1).

There may be different ways of resolving localhost sometimes, but really, why would you not want to put it in there? There is no good reason not to.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. Why would you not want to put it in there? I just want to know if there is any good reason before I ask the sysadmin to do it. So no?

Comment: No. There is no good reason not to put it in there. In fact, I can't even think of a bad reason to leave it out. Leaving it out does nothing except break the system.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it **absolutely should** be defined in the `hosts` file.

Comment: perhaps **absolutely should** is what you mean? Can you provide a link to some supporting documentation?

Comment: @Alex Depends on your OS.  Some handle this resolution elsewhere.

Comment: @Shane Madden Good point, it depends on nsswitch.conf too, it's possible to define localhost not in the hosts file but it should be defined somewhere and I believe default approach is to define it in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @cwd Yeah, absolutely should would be better since there are many OSes in the world besides Linux, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @cwd Regarding the supporting documentation, here is a quotation from `/etc/hosts` on CentOS: `# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost`